# jQuery Mobile Slider decimal output issue in ipad

Tags: ipad, slider, decimal

I need help this time.
Developing poker client right now and one issue just gets me.

Just can't get slider bubble to output properly decimal numbers.

Slider image: http://norwaydict.com/slider.jpg

I'm using Jquery mobile slider plugin.
The output in desktop browsers is OK, but the in ipad is not the same: 
 in ipad decimal number output correctly, but not when number is 1 or 0.40 
 it should output 1.00 or 0.40 but outputs 1 or 0.4, somehow rounds those numbers.

The plugin code if it helps:

```
/*!
 * jQuery Mobile v1.0b2
 * http://jquerymobile.com
 * Copyright 2010, jQuery Project
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*/
/*!
* jQuery UI Widget @VERSION
*
* Copyright 2010, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Widget
*/

/*
* jQuery Mobile Framework : "slider" plugin
* Copyright (c) jQuery Project
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* Forked by Elmundio87 to add vertical orientation
* http://jquery.org/license
*/

( function( $, undefined ) {

$.widget( "mobile.slider", $.mobile.widget, {
options: {
    theme: null,
    trackTheme: null,
    disabled: false,
    initSelector: "input[type='range'], :jqmData(type='range'), :jqmData(role='slider')"
},

_create: function() {

    // TODO: Each of these should have comments explain what they're for
    var self = this,

        control = this.element,

        parentTheme = control.parents( "[class*='ui-bar-'],[class*='ui-body-']" ).eq( 0 ),

        parentTheme = parentTheme.length ? parentTheme.attr( "class" ).match( /ui-(bar|body)-([a-z])/ )[ 2 ] : "c",

        theme = this.options.theme ? this.options.theme : parentTheme,

        trackTheme = this.options.trackTheme ? this.options.trackTheme : parentTheme,

        cType = control[ 0 ].nodeName.toLowerCase(),

        selectClass = ( cType == "select" ) ? "ui-slider-switch" : "",

        controlID = control.attr( "id" ),

        labelID = controlID + "-label",

        label = $( "[for='"+ controlID +"']" ).attr( "id", labelID ),

        val = function() {
            //$('#pool_balance_cashier').html('Slider value3: ' + parseFloat( control.val() ).toFixed(1));

            return  cType == "input"  ? parseFloat( control.val() ).toFixed(2)  : control[0].selectedIndex;
        },

        min =  cType == "input" ? parseFloat( control.attr( "min" ) ) : 0,

        max =  cType == "input" ? parseFloat( control.attr( "max" ) ) : control.find( "option" ).length-1,

        sliderOrientation = control.attr( "sliderOrientation") || "horizontal",

        step = window.parseFloat( control.attr( "step" ) || 1 ),     
        //step = (cType === "input") ? parseFloat(control.attr("step")) : 0,


        slider = $( "<div class='ui-slider-" + sliderOrientation + " " + selectClass + " ui-btn-down-" + trackTheme +
                                " ui-btn-corner-all' role='application'></div>" ),

        handle = $( "<a href='#' class='ui-slider-handle-"+sliderOrientation +"'></a>" )
            .appendTo( slider )
            .buttonMarkup({ corners: true, theme: theme, shadow: true })
            .attr({
                "role": "slider",
                "aria-valuemin": min,
                "aria-valuemax": max,
                "aria-valuenow": val(),
                "aria-valuetext": val(),
                "title": val(),
                "aria-labelledby": labelID
            }),
        options;

    $.extend( this, {
        slider: slider,
        handle: handle,
        dragging: false,
        beforeStart: null
    });

    if ( cType == "select" ) {

        slider.wrapInner( "<div class='ui-slider-inneroffset'></div>" );

        options = control.find( "option" );

        control.find( "option" ).each(function( i ) {

            var side = !i ? "b":"a",
                corners = !i ? "right" :"left",
                theme = !i ? " ui-btn-down-" + trackTheme :" ui-btn-active";

            $( "<div class='ui-slider-labelbg ui-slider-labelbg-" + side + theme + " ui-btn-corner-" + corners + "'></div>" )
                .prependTo( slider );

            $( "<span class='ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-" + side + theme + " ui-btn-corner-" + corners + "' role='img'>" + $( this ).text() + "</span>" )
                .prependTo( handle );
        });

    }

    label.addClass( "ui-slider" );

    // monitor the input for updated values
    control.addClass( cType === "input" ? "ui-slider-input" : "ui-slider-switch" )
        .change( function() {
            self.refresh( val(), true );
        })
        .keyup( function() { // necessary?
            self.refresh( val(), true, true );
        })
        .blur( function() {
            self.refresh( val(), true );
        });

    // prevent screen drag when slider activated
    $( document ).bind( "vmousemove", function( event ) {
        if ( self.dragging ) {
            self.refresh( event );
            return false;
        }
    });

    slider.bind( "vmousedown", function( event ) {
        self.dragging = true;

        if ( cType === "select" ) {
            self.beforeStart = control[0].selectedIndex;
        }
        self.refresh( event );
        return false;
    });

    slider.add( document )
        .bind( "vmouseup", function() {
            if ( self.dragging ) {

                self.dragging = false;

                if ( cType === "select" ) {

                    if ( self.beforeStart === control[ 0 ].selectedIndex ) {
                        //tap occurred, but value didn't change. flip it!
                        self.refresh( !self.beforeStart ? 1 : 0 );
                    }
                    var curval = val();
                    var snapped = Math.round( curval / ( max - min ) * 100 );
                    handle
                        .addClass( "ui-slider-handle-snapping" )
                        .css( "left", snapped + "%" )
                        .animationComplete( function() {
                            handle.removeClass( "ui-slider-handle-snapping" );
                        });
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    slider.insertAfter( control );

    // NOTE force focus on handle
    this.handle
        .bind( "vmousedown", function() {
            $( this ).focus();

               //check cashier slider checkboxes off
               $('#addchips_min').removeClass('pool_checkbox_checked').addClass('pool_checkbox');
               $('#addchips_max').removeClass('pool_checkbox_checked').addClass('pool_checkbox');   

               $('#addchipsLobby_min').removeClass('pool_checkbox_checked').addClass('pool_checkbox');
               $('#addchipsLobby_max').removeClass('pool_checkbox_checked').addClass('pool_checkbox');          

        })
        .bind( "vclick", false );

    this.handle
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            var index = val();      

            if ( self.options.disabled ) {
                return;
            }

            // In all cases prevent the default and mark the handle as active
            switch ( event.keyCode ) {
             case $.mobile.keyCode.HOME:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.END:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.PAGE_UP:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.UP:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.RIGHT:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.DOWN:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.LEFT:
                event.preventDefault();

                if ( !self._keySliding ) {
                    self._keySliding = true;
                    $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-active" );
                }
                break;
            }

            // move the slider according to the keypress
            switch ( event.keyCode ) {
             case $.mobile.keyCode.HOME:
                self.refresh( min );
                break;
             case $.mobile.keyCode.END:
                self.refresh( max );
                break;
             case $.mobile.keyCode.PAGE_UP:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.UP:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.RIGHT:
                self.refresh( index + step );
                break;
             case $.mobile.keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.DOWN:
             case $.mobile.keyCode.LEFT:
                self.refresh( index - step );
                break;
            }
        }) // remove active mark
        .keyup( function( event ) {
            if ( self._keySliding ) {
                self._keySliding = false;
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-active" );
            }
        });

    this.refresh(undefined, undefined, true);
},

refresh: function( val, isfromControl, preventInputUpdate ) {

    if ( this.options.disabled ) { return; }

    var control = this.element, percent,
        cType = control[0].nodeName.toLowerCase(),
        min = cType === "input" ? parseFloat( control.attr( "min" ) ) : 0,
        max = cType === "input" ? parseFloat( control.attr( "max" ) ) : control.find( "option" ).length - 1;
        sliderOrientation = control.attr( "sliderOrientation") || "horizontal";

    if ( typeof val === "object" ) {
        var data = val,
            // a slight tolerance helped get to the ends of the slider
            tol = 8;

        if(sliderOrientation == "horizontal"){  
            if ( !this.dragging || data.pageX < this.slider.offset().left - tol || data.pageX > this.slider.offset().left + this.slider.width() + tol ) {return;}
        }
        else
        {
            if ( !this.dragging || data.pageY < this.slider.offset().top - tol || data.pageY > this.slider.offset().top + this.slider.height() + tol ) {return;}
        }


        if(sliderOrientation == "horizontal")
        {
          percent = Math.round( ( ( data.pageX - this.slider.offset().left ) / this.slider.width() ) * 100 );
        }
        else
        {
          percent = Math.round( ( ( data.pageY - this.slider.offset().top ) / this.slider.height() ) * 100 );
        }

    } else {
        if ( val == null ) {
            val = cType === "input" ? parseFloat( control.val() ) : control[0].selectedIndex;
        }
        percent = ( parseFloat( val ) - min ) / ( max - min ) * 100;
    }

    if ( isNaN( percent ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( percent < 0 ) {
        percent = 0;
    }

    if ( percent > 100 ) {
        percent = 100;
    }



    //var newval = Math.round( ( percent / 100 ) * ( max - min ) ) + min;

    // newval needs to support floating point min / max values, and must round to the step value
    var newval = (percent / 100) * (max - min) + min;
    newval -= (((newval - min) * 100) % (0.01 * 100)) / 100;
    //newval = Math.round(newval * 100 + 0.01) / 100;
    newval = Utils.formatFloatVal((newval * 100 + 0.01) / 100, false, true);
    //$('#pool_balance_cashier').html('Slider value: ' + newval);

    if(canvas != null){
        if(canvas.width < 560){ //only for iphone
          $('#iphone_amountIndicator').html('<br> ' + newval); 
          $('#slider-bet').hide();
          $('#slider-bet .ui-slider-handle').hide();
        }else{
          $('#iphone_amountIndicator').empty();
          $('#slider-bet').show();
        }
    }

    //set div that indicates how much we choose to bet with slider
    //$(".amountIndicator").width(percent * 280 / 100);
    if(control.attr('id') == 'slider-cashier'){
        $("#amountIndicator_settings").width(percent * 280 / 102);
    }
    else if(control.attr('id') == 'slider-lobby-cashier'){
        $("#amountIndicator_lobby").width(percent * 280 / 100);
    }
    else{
        $("#amountIndicator_pool").width(percent * 280 / 100);
    }


    //set label amount to bet/raise button
    //$('#prc_pool_notice').html(' <br><br> ----- Slider value: ' + newval + ' this.id: ' + control.attr( "id" ) + ' ----- <br>');
    if(buttons.btns != null){
        if(buttons.btns[3].active){
            buttons.btns[3].label_amount = GL_CURRENCY_SIGN+newval;   
        }
        else if(buttons.btns[4].active){
            buttons.btns[4].label_amount = '€'+newval;      
        }
    }


    if ( newval < min ) {
        newval = min;
    }

    if ( newval > max ) {
        newval = max;
    }

    // Flip the stack of the bg colors
    if ( percent > 60 && cType === "select" ) {
        // TODO: Dead path?
    }


    if(sliderOrientation == "horizontal")
    {
        //for slider cahsier -> not to very end of slide panel
        if(control.attr('id') != 'slider-bet'){
            this.handle.css( "left", percent / 1.3 + "%" ); 
            if(percent > 50){
                this.handle.css( "left", percent/1.17 + "%" ); 
            }       
        }else{
            this.handle.css( "left", percent + "%" ); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.handle.css( "top", percent + "%" );
    }

    this.handle.attr( {
            "aria-valuenow": cType === "input" ? newval : control.find( "option" ).eq( newval ).attr( "value" ),
            "aria-valuetext": cType === "input" ? newval : control.find( "option" ).eq( newval ).text(),
            title: newval 
        });

    // add/remove classes for flip toggle switch
    if ( cType === "select" ) {
        if ( newval === 0 ) {
            this.slider.addClass( "ui-slider-switch-a" )
                .removeClass( "ui-slider-switch-b" );
        } else {
            this.slider.addClass( "ui-slider-switch-b" )
                .removeClass( "ui-slider-switch-a" );
        }
    }

    if ( !preventInputUpdate ) {
        // update control"s value
        if ( cType === "input" ) {
            control.val( newval );
        } else {
            control[ 0 ].selectedIndex = newval;
        }
        if ( !isfromControl ) {
            control.trigger( "change" );
        }
    }
},

enable: function() {
    this.element.attr( "disabled", false );
    this.slider.removeClass( "ui-disabled" ).attr( "aria-disabled", false );
    return this._setOption( "disabled", false );
},

disable: function() {
    this.element.attr( "disabled", true );
    this.slider.addClass( "ui-disabled" ).attr( "aria-disabled", true );
    return this._setOption( "disabled", true );
}

});

  //auto self-init widgets
 $( document ).bind( "pagecreate create", function( e ){

$( $.mobile.slider.prototype.options.initSelector, e.target )
    .not( ":jqmData(role='none'), :jqmData(role='nojs')" )
    .slider();

  });

})( jQuery );
```

Have feeling

```
    val = function() {
          //$('#pool_balance_cashier').html('Slider value3: ' + parseFloat( control.val() ).toFixed(1));

          return  cType == "input"  ? parseFloat( control.val() ).toFixed(2)  :   control[0].selectedIndex;
    },
```

something to do with output.

Would appriciate if you help on this one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 data type="number" could be the culprit if that is how the field is being rendered. On iOS, it removes trailing zeros. It's annoying. The typical fix is to just make it a type="text" field.

Comment: Well, actually I have input type = range element

<div id="div-slider-cashier">
          <label for="slider-cashier"></label>
          <div id='amountIndicator_settings' class='amountIndicator'></div>
          <input type="range" min="0.25" max="1" disabled="disabled" value="0.25" step="0.01" id="slider-cashier" /> 
        </div>

Comment: On iOS, a slider is rendered as a slider...so not numeric output (visually). Where is the output you are having issues displayed?

Comment: I think it's created dynamically here: 

    control.find( "option" ).each(function( i ) {

    var side = !i ? "b":"a",
    corners = !i ? "right" :"left",
    theme = !i ? " ui-btn-down-" + trackTheme :" ui-btn-active";

    
    $( "<div class='ui-slider-labelbg ui-slider-labelbg-" + side + theme + " ui-btn-corner-" + corners + "'></div>" )
     .prependTo( slider );

    $( "<span class='ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-" + side + theme + " ui-btn-corner-" + corners + "' role='img'>" + $( this ).text() + "</span>" )
     .prependTo( handle );
   });

Comment: You meant link with working demo? I don't think I can show you right now, still in development.

Comment: I meant what do you mean by 'output'? Is the number rendered on the page somewhere? If so, how? What HTML? Or do you mean you're grabbing the value programtically (in JS)?

Comment: I mean all vital parts are create dynamically in js plugin 
output is some control element that plugin creates, I just need to know what element and why it rounds data in ipad, since the data I formated well -> it renders in some div element correctly but in not in the bubble -> some html element created by plugin.

Comment: We need to know what those HTML elements are. Open up firebug and grab the rendered HTML.

Comment: <a class="ui-slider-handle-horizontal ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-theme="c" role="slider" aria-valuemin="40" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="15.00" aria-valuetext="15.00" title="15.00" aria-labelledby="slider-cashier-label" style="left: 15.3846%;">

That is what say desktop Firefox.

Comment: that's an anchor tag. That in and of itself has no next. Was there text inside the anchor tag? Either way, since it doesn't appear to be an input field, my guess is that JS may stripping trailing zeros. You may have to add them back with JS.